# abstract class and oop

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I know that we can not instantiate an object from abstract class but what is happening in the following code :

```
while(!stack.empty())
     {
         Shape s1 = (Shape) stack.pop();
         // more code here not important
     }
```

here "Shape" is an abstract class,then what is going on here ???
" Shape s1 " is he making an object or what is he doing ??

whole code :

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    protected double area;
    public abstract double getArea(); 
}

public class Circle extends Shape
{
     double radius;
     public Circle(double r)
     {
         radius = r;
     }
     public double getArea()
     {
         area = 3.14*(radius*radius);
         return area;
     }
}
```

Note : he is pushing in stack objects from Circle type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Circle is the only non-abstract extension of Shape all instances within the stack are Circle. By extending Shape your Class Circle can be assigned to a Circle or a Shape reference.
The same for classes implementing interfaces like

```
List × = new ArrayList();
```

with Interface List and its implementation ArrayList

Comment: so here he is making a reference to the popped objects, not making a new object(as it is rejected due to abstract) ? and he chooses "Shape" for the reference as Shape is the parent of all shapes

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the OOP principles calls [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). You cast an instance to abstract class (or an interface) `Shape`, but instance itself should be any of concrete class that is child of `Shape`.